# Python Find string between given delimiters in function

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on this game on checkio.org. Its a python game and this level I need to find the word between two defined delimiters. The function calls them. So far I have done alright but I can't get any more help from google probably because I don't know how to ask for what i need.

Anyways I am stuck and I would like to know where I am messing this up.

```
def between_markers(text: str, begin: str, end: str) -> str:
    """
        returns substring between two given markers
    """
    # your code here

    s = text

    #find the index for begin and end
    b = s.find(begin) + len(begin)
    c = s.find(end,b)
    #if there is a beginning delimiter return string from between
    if begin in s:
        return s[b:c]
    # if the begin is not the only return until end delimiter
    elif begin not in s:
        return s[:-c]
    #if the ending delimiter isnt there return from beinning to end of string
    elif end not in s:
        return s[b:]
    #if both delimiters are missing just return the text
    elif begin or end not in s:
        return s



if __name__ == '__main__':
    #    print('Example:')
    #    print(between_markers('What is >apple<', '>', '<'))

    # These "asserts" are used for self-checking and not for testing
    assert between_markers('What is >apple<', '>', '<') == "apple", "One sym"
    assert between_markers("<head><title>My new site</title></head>",
                                 "<title>", "</title>") == "My new site", "HTML"
    assert between_markers('No[/b] hi', '[b]', '[/b]') == 'No', 'No opened'
    assert between_markers('No [b]hi', '[b]', '[/b]') == 'hi', 'No close'
    assert between_markers('No hi', '[b]', '[/b]') == 'No hi', 'No markers at all'
    assert between_markers('No <hi>', '>', '<') == '', 'Wrong direction'
    print('Wow, you are doing pretty good. Time to check it!')
```

I am stuck here wondering where I am wrong.

`elif begin not in s:
    return s[:c]`: is where its going to hell. `return s[:c]` in theory should return everything up to `c` but it cuts off one letter before the end of the string and every slice i use cuts it off by one character. this `assert between_markers('No [b]hi', '[b]', '[/b]') == 'hi', 'No close'` gives me `h` not `hi`. Using `[:-c]` fails me on the previous assert...

Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: isint this udacity homework/

Comment: please correct your indentation

Comment: @elithesaiyan it's from checkio. I wouldn't normally ask but this is literally keeping me up at night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hackey with the nested `if b > 5` but it works

```
def between_markers(text: str, begin: str, end: str) -> str:
s = text

# find the index for begin and end
b = s.find(begin)  # -1 if not found
c = s.find(end, b + len(begin))  # search only after begins match, -1 if not found

    if b != -1 and c == -1:   # only b found
        if b > 5:
            return ""
        else:
            return s[b + len(begin):]

    if b == -1 and c == -1:   # neither found
        return s

    if b != -1 and c != -1:     # both found
        return s[b + len(begin):c]

    if b == -1 and c != -1:   # only c found
        return s[:c]

    else:  # none found
        return ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Slicing works not like you think it does:

```
s = "012345"
p = s[1:3] 
print(p)
```

prints

```
12
```

It slices from `1` **inclusive** to `3` **exclusive**.

---

`str.find()` returns -1 if it does not find anything. If you add the length of `begin` to `-1` (no begin found) and then start looking from this position for `end` you have a logic error. Depending on the texts and markers you get errors.

You can make your comparisons far easier to handle if you not immediatly add the lenght of the begin-tag to the (possibly) -1 result from find for that tag.

```
def between_markers(text: str, begin: str, end: str) -> str:
    """ returns substring between two given markers """  
    s = text

    #find the index for begin and end
    b = s.find(begin)                # -1 if not found
    c = s.find(end, b+len(begin))    # search only after begins match, -1 if not found

    if b > -1 and b < c:             # both found, b before c (not strictly needed) as                         
        return s[b+len(begin):c]     # c is always "after" b - makes more sense 2 me

    elif b == -1 and c > -1:         # only c found
        return s[:c]

    elif b > -1 and c == -1:         # only b found
        return s[b+len(begin):]

    else:                            # none found
        return s
```

passes your self written asserts.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that. I've googled my brains out trying to get vetter descriptions of methods and have not been so lucky. Guess I need to go back and work more on learnpython

Comment: That didnt work. Failed on this `between_markers("No <hi> one",">","<")` which is not in an assert.

Comment: it prints `one` when it shouldnt.